# $2x^{1/3} = 3y^{1/5}$, What is largest possible integer of $xy$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$2x^{1/3} = 3y^{1/5}$$
>
> What is largest possible integer of $xy$?

I need to determine the largest possible value of $xy.$

I couldn't solve this cause there is only one equation.

Comment: Eliminate $y$ (i.e. express $y$ as a function of $x$).

Comment: Infinity? Is it not unbounded as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Do you want the smallest positive value of $xy$.

Answer (score 3):

If we rearrange the original equation to find $x$, we get: $x=\frac{27}{8}y^{3/5}$

This gives $xy=\frac{27}{8}y^{8/5}$

So our maximum is $\max(xy)=\max(\frac{27}{8}y^{8/5})$.

Since this goes to $\infty$ as $y\to\infty$, our maximum is $\infty$ (i.e. we have no maximum). Our result is the same if $xy$ is an integer or if it's any real (either way, it tends to infinity).

You could also do this the other way round, solving for $y$ & finding $xy$ in terms of $x$. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation Find x in terms of y. Then substitute x in xy. From graphing that I can say there can be no finite max value. Though the lowest value can be 0.